# iOS7 - why do elements of the page shift when I view things as iOS 6 or 7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, storyboard

I am upgrading an app to comply with iOS7. But I am having some strange behavior.

As you can see from the screen shot below, when I view things as iOS 6.1, for some reason, the UIListView item gets pushed down when it is set to be right below the buttons in the storyboard.

[image]

But when I view things as iOS7 and run the app, it appears as it was intended..shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Would anyone know why this happens, and what is the correct way to handle this kind of a situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status bar on iOS 7 doesn't take away the space.  It overlays it the same way the navigation bar does.  So you have an extra 20px to account for.

Check for iOS 7 and handle the frame of your objects.

You can check the iOS version with this

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
```

Comment: I think you missed the point a little bit. See on the screenshots, an element in the middle of the page got shifted down - not all page elements.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's getting shifted the full height of the nav bar and status bar.  Maybe check your auto layout struts for the tableview

Comment: what are the auto-layout strats for the tableview?

Comment: The docs explain and show it better than I can. Click the tableview and then click the layout button. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.htmlj

Comment: are you suggesting I turn off auto-layout? Or are you talking about a different layout button?

Comment: Try turning it off and see it if helps.  You could also just check the iOS version and hard code the position of the objects you're having issues with.